# Fabric.js Text transform not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, transform, fabricjs

I am unable to apply a `transformMatrix` to a Text object in Fabric.

The problem is illustrated here:
http://jsfiddle.net/d8Tkj/1/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.add(new fabric.Text('Transform does not work', {
    fontSize:20,
    left:0,
    top:0,
    'transformMatrix': [1,0,0,1,0,200] // should translate by 200px down. But this does not work
}));


canvas.add(new fabric.Text('But this works', {
    fontSize:20,
    left:0,
    top:200
}));

// transform works on other objects:
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left:0,
    top:0,
    width:50,
    height:50,
    fill:'red',
    'transformMatrix': [1,0,0,1,100,100]
}));
```

Has anyone else seen this issue? I know I can translate by changing position, but I need to be able to use the transform matrix for my app.

Comment: I'm not sure how `transformMatrix` should work with interactive objects. Notice how draggable area of rectangle is not where rectangle itself is rendered.

Comment: Okay, I didn't notice that before. But still, does transformMatrix not apply to Text objects?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't. Please file an issue on github, I'll look into it.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transformMatrix for text is working fine in the newest version of the fabric.js ie. 1.4.1
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

check above link.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
    left:100,
    top:100,
    width:50,
    height:50,
    fill:'red',
    'transformMatrix': [1,0,0,1,0,0]
}));
```

try to give top and left instead of giving it in transform matrix

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate item you can simply use

```
const text = new fabric.Text('Text label', { angle: 90 })
OR
text.angle = 90;
```